# How to make the top-right corner of a surface the passed in location to a rectangle?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a maze game where I control a player and I have to run from aliens that are moving towards me. I make use of a pathfinder to make the aliens move towards me but I notice that the aliens always go through the maze blocks, but only a small part of the alien is shown. Since the dimensions of the alien are 15x15 I think I can only see 1x15, it is not very clear. I learned that this happens because I passed in the top-left corner of the alien as the x-coord and y-coord.

I wanted to find ways to pass in the top-right corner, bottom right corner and the bottom left corner instead.

I have tried looking at the python documentation for sprites and surfaces but they only show how to pass the top left corner.

I have looked at youtube videos but again only top left corner.

I have looked at https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html and it shows this: top-left, bottom left, top right, bottom-right. I don't think it is relevant since this is pygame.Rect but I am using pygame.sprite.Sprite.

```
class MyAlien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, health):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15]) # object 15px wide and 15px high
        self.image.fill(RED) # fill in red color

        # top-left corner is our passed in location
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y # set x coord
        self.rect.x = x # set y coord
```

I expect a self.rect = self.image.get_rect() equvilant for top right, bottom right, and bottom left corners of the alien.

Comment: I don't understand where you're stuck.  You know the top-left corner and the dimensions of the rectangle.  Finding the other corners follows directly from that.

Comment: I know how to find that. The problem is that when trying to move the player pygame automatically starts from the top-left for rectangles. And from there you get the top right corner x,y and so on. But instead of making the top-left corner as the reference point I want to make the top-right, bottom right and bottom left corner references as well in different scenarios. I'm gonna try and do what, Rabbid76, suggested.

Comment: Yup; I'm one of the up-votes on that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the top right coordinate, then you've to set [`.topright`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) rather than `.x` and `.y`.
Just assign a tuple to `self.rect.topright`:

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.topright = (x, y) # set top right
```

Note, [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) provides virtual attributes to get and set `.topleft`, `.bottomleft`, `.topright`, `.bottomright` and many more. `.x` sets the left coordinate and `.y` the top coordinate.

---

> I don't think it is relevant since this is pygame.Rect but I am using pygame.sprite.Sprite.

Of course it is relevant to set the coordinates of the `.rect` attribute, because the [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object uses this attribute to store its location. The `.rect` attribute is read in [`.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) to put the `.image` at its place.